# Smart contract and Coin integration

Tags: ether, truffle-contract, tokens

I understand how to create contracts in Solidity, and how to create a Coin using Openzepplin. I do not understand how to integrate both.

Let say that every transaction on contract (MyContract), will use a coin (MyCoin). The value of Mycoin is based on ether.

Any link that provides a simple implementation for this kind of intergration would be helpful.